# XML Schema redefinition error

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to redefine the `maxOccurs` attribute of an element in a simple XML Schema using Eclipse's WTP plugin as my IDE.

File: widget1.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/widget"
  elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/widget">

  <xsd:complexType name="WidgetType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="ProductID" type="xsd:unsignedInt"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:element name="Widgets">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Widget" type="tns:WidgetType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="65536"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

File: widget2.xsd
In this file I want to redefine the `maxOccurs` attribute for `Widget` to 10.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/widget" elementFormDefault="qualified"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/widget">

  <xsd:include schemaLocation="widget1.xsd"/>

  <xsd:redefine schemaLocation="widget1.xsd">
    <xsd:complexType name="Widgets">
      <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:restriction base="Widgets">
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="tns:Widget" maxOccurs="10"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:restriction>
      </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:redefine>

</xsd:schema>
```

However, validation fails on widget2.xsd and Eclipse reports this error

`Multiple annotations found at this line:`

```
    - src-resolve.4.1: Error resolving component 'Widgets'. It was detected that 'Widgets' has no namespace, but components with no target namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'file:///C:/Projects/Test/XMLSchema/Widget/widget2.xsd'. If 'Widgets' is intended to have a namespace, perhaps a prefix needs to be provided. If it is intended that 'Widgets' has no namespace, then an 'import' without a "namespace" attribute should be added to 'file:///C:/Projects/Test/XMLSchema/Widget/widget2.xsd'.

    - src-redefine.5.b.d: 'restriction' does not have a 'base' attribute that refers to the redefined element, 'http://www.example.org/widget,Widgets'. <complexType> children of <redefine> elements must have <extension> or <restriction> descendants, with 'base' attributes that refer to themselves.
```

I tried replacing `Widgets` in the `<redefine>` with `tns:Widgets` hoping to get rid of the namespace error but that doesn't work either.

What does this error mean? And is what I'm trying to do possible at all?

Comment: redefine's are poorly supported and add a lot of complexity to a schema set, if at all possible I would avoid using them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I managed to figure this one out after a lot of trial and error! The problem seems to have been that in `widget1.xsd` the type for the `Widgets` element was being created as an anonymous local type. Once I separated the type into its own local `WidgetsType` it fixed the problem. I'd appreciate it if anybody could answer why. I'm pasting the modified files, maybe it'll help someone else.

File: widget1.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/widget"
  elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/widget">

  <xsd:complexType name="WidgetType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="ProductID" type="xsd:unsignedInt"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="WidgetsType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Widget" type="tns:WidgetType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="65536"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:element name="Widgets" type="tns:WidgetsType"/>

</xsd:schema>
```

File: widget2.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/widget"
  elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/widget">

  <xsd:redefine schemaLocation="widget1.xsd">
    <xsd:complexType name="WidgetsType">
      <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:restriction base="tns:WidgetsType">
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Widget" type="tns:WidgetType" maxOccurs="10"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:restriction>
      </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:redefine>

  <xsd:element name="Widgets" type="tns:WidgetsType" />

</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first include in your first post ist not allowed. Redefine acts like include too.

And you have to declare, the type in your redefined-Element. You can't just make it anonymous.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution works because in the original *widget2.xsd* your try to `redefine` the element `Widgets`", but redefine only allows you to redefine types ... that's what you tried in your solution.